# how do I exec a task in a screen session with fabric?

Tags: fabric

In fabric, what's the easiest way to run a long-running command in a detached state, such as in a `screen` session, so that I can disconnect and it would continue to run?

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393374/how-to-use-fabric-use-with-dtach-screen-is-there-some-example),

it should work using

`sun("screen yourcommand")`