# Start detached Unix process via fabric on multiple servers and retrieve status?

Tags: python, fabric

What is the recommended way to start long running (bash) scripts on several remote servers via fabric, so that you can later re-attach to the process for checking the status of the process, eventually sigterm it and get the exit code?

**EDIT** (10-Nov-2012):

In the mean-time I found a question going into the same direction: [HOW TO use fabric use with dtach,screen,is there some example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393374/how-to-use-fabric-use-with-dtach-screen-is-there-some-example)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the preferred way would be to use screen or tmux.

http://www.fabfile.org/faq.html#why-can-t-i-run-programs-in-the-background-with-it-makes-fabric-hang

Comment: Maybe you should stress the mandatory NOHUP invocation. and in context with fully automated fabric session dtach might be the best tool.

Comment: Thanks -- yes, I read in the fabric FAQ about the options to leverage screen, tmux or dtach, but am still wondering about how this would workout in real world and not run in any timeout issues